# SPA website, would making an HTML-only version for SEO be worthy?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, javascript, single-page-application

I made a Vue.js SPA, and since it could affect SEO (specially because a large portion of my client base is not using Google), I was thinking: why not providing an HTML-only version for it?

Would there be any real benefit or are search engines in general (other than major and well financed search engines like Google) already capable enough to execute JavaScript?

I'm thinking an HTML version focused on content would be more SEO-friendly. But since I haven't found any tools that do it nor any blog post talking about it, it may not be such a good idea.

Note: in my case, doing such a version would not be a big effort (it would even be quite easy actually).

Comment: You are probably looking for "pre-rendering" for your Vue.js app.

Answer (score 1):

I had such experience. Our website is also built with Vue.js and we created an SSR version which will only be shown to search engine robots.

This is also recommended by Google that if you want your JS client-side rendered website to be indexed (rendered ) faster by crawlers, provide an SSR version to it.

It's called dynamic indexing. You can find more info [here](http://forums.seochat.com/search-engine-optimization-28/deliver-different-version-website-google-robots-495974.html).
You can also find information about dynamic indexing [here](https://youtu.be/PFwUbgvpdaQ?t=1080).

Comment: @hl037_ What do you mean?

Comment: the name "dynamic indexing" I didn't knew about

Comment: Yes it's quite a new consept that Google introduced in Google I/O '18